# How to ignore specfic xml elements using xmlunit when comparing two xml files in junit

Tags: java, junit, xml-parsing, xmlunit

I tried to write a test case in `JUnit` for comparing two xml files. Using `xmlunit`, I should be able to find all the differences. But while comparing, I'm getting `false` all the time, though I am giving similar kind of files. Timestamp is different for each xml file. So, though all the other contents in xml file are equal, it is returning false. Please provide me any proper way to handle this problem.

I need to ignore the timestamp tag in the xml file when comparing two xml files. And how do I ignore self closing tags?

```
<XML>
<TIMESTAMP>KALA</TIMESTAMP>
<B>JIHN</B>
<C>Lion</C>
</XML>

<XML>
<TIMESTAMP>QWER</TIMESTAMP>
<B>JIHN</B>
<C NAME =LION/>
</XML>
<B>JIHN</B>
```

Comment: Could you pass the XML through an XSLT template that strips out all the unwanted parts, before you do the comparison?

Answer (score 1):

XMLUnit 2.x has the concept of `NodeFilter`s, using that you can easily ignore the `TIMESTAMP` elements. Something like

```
String control = "<XML>\n"
    + "<TIMESTAMP>KALA</TIMESTAMP>\n"
    + "<B>JIHN</B>\n"
    + "<C>Lion</C>\n"
    + "</XML>";
String test = "<XML>\n"
    + "<TIMESTAMP>QWER</TIMESTAMP>\n"
    + "<B>JIHN</B>\n"
    + "<C NAME=\"LION\"/>\n"
    + "</XML>";
Diff d = DiffBuilder.compare(Input.fromString(control))
    .withTest(Input.fromString(test))
    .withNodeFilter(n -> !(n instanceof Element && Nodes.getQName(n).getLocalPart().equals("TIMESTAMP")))
    .build();
```

could be a start.

I'm not sure what you mean by self-closing tags. `<x></x>` and `<x/>` are identical as far as XMLUnit is concerned. The `C` elements in your example clearly are not. The first one has no attributes but a nested text, the second one has an attribute named `NAME` but no nested test.

Comment: I couldn't undetstand the code.Please explain me in detail about how to implement in code. when I give string for TEST , I  got an error. Test  doesn't accepting the  string."Diff d = DiffBuilder.compare(CONTROL).with(TEST)" . I would like to ignore two different elements of the xml file  other than timestamp. Waiting for your help. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Teena I've edited the post to contain your full examples rather than placeholders (and made your second example well-formed XML by adding quotes around the `NAME` attribute's value and omitting the second `B`). The code compiles and if you run it `d` will not contain any differences about `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. it was helpful. one more added to this I want to ignore more than one tags ,how can I achieve this? and the result also its returning identical. How can I print  other differences too

Comment: @Teena the `NodeFilter` really only is a boolean expression on `Node`s. So if you want to ignore other nodes as well, just create write a predicate that selects all of them, like looking up whether the local name is member inside a set of black-listed names. I'm not sure I understand the second part of your question. If you tell `DiffBuilder` to `checkForSimilar` you get all the differences.